# Eliminate the [home] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[home](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/home) is an undefined tag with one question and it is closed as off-topic.  Is this a needed tag?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Tag has been removed.